# i copy and paste my code from another form but when it reaches 10 it stops counting only print more 10

Tags: vb.net, max, sqlclient

Instead of counting 1,2,3,4,5...infinity it counts like this 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,10,10,10,10,10...

I don't see what's wrong and it does not have any error.

```
Private Sub GenID()
    If sql.cnn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
        sql.cnn.Open()
    End If

    Dim sqlstring As String
    Dim command As New SqlCommand
    sqlstring = "SELECT MAX(RIGHT(no,6)) as no from CodeTBL"
    command.Connection = sql.cnn
    command = New SqlCommand(sqlstring, sql.cnn)
    sql.sqldr = command.ExecuteReader
    sql.sqldr.Read()
    If Not sql.sqldr.HasRows Or IsDBNull(sql.sqldr.Item("no")) Then
        TextBox8.Text = +"000001"
    Else
        Dim news As Integer = CInt(sql.sqldr.Item("no"))
        news += 1
        TextBox8.Text = news.ToString("000000")
    End If
    sql.sqldr.Close()
    sql.cnn.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: 1) If you use [Option Strict On](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx) it will point out that `TextBox8.Text = +"000001"` is not valid code. 2) You should not have a global sql object of some sort - it will only lead to problems. 3) You did not say what the datatype of the databse column `[no]` is. 4) It is usually better to get the database to automatically create IDs.

Comment: You're also using `HasRows` wrong.  It should be called _before_ you call `Read`.